# How to create a boolean template variable in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I want to show or hide a section by click of a button. I don't want to create a variable in the controller. Is there a way to do this by using local template variables (using `#variableName`)?

I am thinking something like below.
But for this I am getting `template parse error`.

```
  <button color="primary" #showSection1="true" (click)="!showSection1;">Toggle</button>
  <p *ngIf="showSection1">
    This should be shown or hidden on click of the button.
  </p>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do it that way because template variable stores entire `button` element when you declare it like that, but you can take advantage of ternary operator here:

```
<button (click)="showSection1 ? showSection1 = false : showSection1 = true;">Toggle</button>
<p *ngIf="showSection1">
    This should be shown or hidden on click of the button.
</p>
```

When `showSection1` is undefined or has false value, it will be set to true and vice versa.

Here's working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/p0tZm8S8l32nRLlPdMX6?p=preview).

Comment: Or a bit shorter `(click)="showSection1 = !showSection1"`

Comment: this will throw a transpile/compile error since  showSection1  is not defined on the parent component

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do this in a way that will work with AOT (Production) compilation, I would recommend using a template reference variable.  For my example, I want to have the class `open` applied to my element when it is closed, and removed when it is clicked again. Basically, I want to toggle the `open` class on my element.  Storing this state data in my component.ts file is ugly in my opinion.

To achieve this I do the following.

```
<li class="tagTag" 
  *ngFor="let tag of tagCategory.tags"
  [ngClass]="{'open': toggle.value}" 
  #toggle [value]="false" 
  (click)="toggle.value = !toggle.value">...</li>
```

the `#toggle` stores the `<li>` instance as a Template Reference Variable called 'toggle'. I then use the `value` directive and give it a value of `false`.  Using the click handler, I set the value of the value directive between true and false. My `[ngClass]` adds or removes the open class based upon the current value of the value directive on this template reference. This works with ahead-of-time compilation and allows you to keep superfluous variables out of your component.  Use this with care though because, almost as a rule, you do not want to define variables in a template.

Answer (score 0):

you may use below,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
   <label>
        <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="showSection1" >
        Is Shown
    </label>
    <p *ngIf="showSection1">
      This should be shown or hidden on click of the button.
    </p>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { name = 'Angular'; }
```

Here is [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pKU17rpg8pc22QIUnrVP?p=preview)!!

Hope this helps!!